# How do I simplify this, I forgot some algebra, thanks for any help!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help , I forgot how to simplify an expression that has 1 term in numerator and two terms in denominator. Forgot some algebra with fractions, thanks for any help

$$_{}   \frac{1}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2x} +\frac{1}{2y}}$$

Comment: What would happen if you found a common denominator for those two fractions in the bottom and combined them?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac1{0.5(x+y)}$ or $\frac1{\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{2y}}?$

Comment: I mean your second option (sorry Im trying to get faster at the formatting) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{1}{2x}=\frac{1}{2x}\frac{2y}{2y}=\frac{2y}{2x\cdot 2y}=\frac{y}{2xy}$$
$$\frac{1}{2y}=\frac{1}{2y}\frac{2x}{2x}=\frac{2x}{2x\cdot 2y}=\frac{x}{2xy}$$

Now  $\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{2y}$ is?

Answer (score 1):

Focus on the denominator first.

$$_{}   \frac{1}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2x} +\frac{1}{2y}}= _{}   \frac{1}{\displaystyle\frac{2y}{2x2y} +\frac{2x}{2y2x}}=  \frac{1}{ \displaystyle\frac{2y +2x}{2x2y} }= \frac{1}{ \displaystyle\frac{y +x}{2xy}} $$

Flip the last equation into it's reciprocal and you get your simplified equation.

$$_{} { \displaystyle\frac{2xy}{y +x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $2xy$ and get
$$\frac{1}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2x} +\frac{1}{2y}}=\frac{2xy}{y+x}.$$